# Need code to click "OK" in "Are you sure?" prompt for automating form submission using 2Captcha extension on chrome

Tags: javascript, popup, recaptcha, ui-automation, 2captcha

I want to automate form submission. To submit the form, I need to first complete a recaptcha, for which I use 2Captcha chrome extension.

I am trying to use 2captcha AutoSubmit feature, but it unfortunately is getting stuck because when it completes recaptcha and clicks SUBMIT, a pop up "Are you sure?" appears at top - in which the user needs to click "OK".

2Captcha allows user to add a code that can also click "OK" in this "Are you sure?" popup, thus making the process fully automated.

But I have no idea at all what code to use in 2captcha that can do so. I hope it's a simple code.

Any help will be *hugely* appreciated.

Thanks!

Currently, when I try using AutoSubmit feature it gets stuck at "Are you sure?" popup. I need to add a code to 2Captcha that can click "OK" to that "Are you sure?" popup.

Comment: Hello Wasim, Every time you are facing that popup for confirmation ?

Comment: Hi Hetal. Yes, I must click "OK" to the "Are you sure?" prompt every single time. Only then, can the form submit.